# Convert .tex file into PNG

Tags: linux, perl, unix, png, tex

Does any one here know how to convert a .tex file into png using perl?

#### `.tex` file content:

```
\begin{equation*}
\quad\!{\rm BP}({\rm gCL}^{ - 1} {\rm h}^{ - 1} ) = {\rm mol}\;{\rm CL}^{ - 1} {{\rm h}^{ - 1}} _{{\rm inc}} \times 1797 \times 0.86
\end{equation*}
```

Is there a method in Perl that can convert this in PNG?

Comment: See [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible)

Comment: Thank you Håkon! But I'm hoping to use a standalone that needs no installation. Would that be possible?

Comment: I am not sure.. You should ask at [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google's Charts API: `http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=\begin{equation*}%20\quad!{\rm%20BP}%28{\rm%20gCL}^{%20-%201}%20{\rm%20h}^{%20-%201}%20%29%20=%20{\rm%20mol}\;{\rm%20CL}^{%20-%201}%20{{\rm%20h}^{%20-%201}}%20_{{\rm%20inc}}%20\times%201797%20\times%200.86%20\end{equation*}`

See [Google's Deprecated Image Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/making_charts).

[image: LaTeX rendered as PNG]

See also my crappy Template.pm plugin [Template::Plugin::GoogleLaTeX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Plugin::GoogleLaTeX). I am not sure if it still works.